# Using Ethereum Classic with web3.py

Tags: ethereum-classic, python

I successfully integrated Ethereum (ETH) in my product. Now, I want to integrate Ethereum Classic(ETC) in my product. I am using web3.py for ETH. Are there any documentations or libraries for ETC? How to get started with ETC? Please help

Comment: ETH is a fork of ETC so most of the things are the same. How do you need to integrate ETC into your project? What is different for ETH compared to ETC in your project?

Comment: I using ETH  in my wallet. I am using ETH with web3.py library. My wallet has to support ETC. There is no difference. I have thought both are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not separate library or documentation needed. Ethereum Classic and Ethereum nodes share the same JSON-RPC API.

Just point your web3.py `HTTPProvider` to Ethereum Classic node.

Comment: could you tell me how to generate private and public addresses using web3.py?

Comment: @merklexy This would be an another question. Please follow the format of Q&A site and open a new question for a different question.